# Unable to use the terminal in Rubymine 6.3.3 on Windows 8

Tags: rubymine

I downloaded Rubymine 6.3.3 and I have Windows 8. When I open the terminal only the version and copyright appears without the path and I am unable to type anything. I checked the settings and the plugin is enabled and the terminal options seem to set correctly

any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Did you set up the env variable ?

Comment: No, but i did not need to do so in windows 7. How do i set it here?

Comment: Your RubyMine is too old (current version is 8.0.3). Please try latest version: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/download/